Passing complex structure to Fragment Shader
I am generating some geometries, in this case the Mandelbrot Fractal. It is calculated entirely in the fragment shader. And there is a structure MandelbrotBase, containing different settings, like window size, position, zoom etc. Right now it is only part of Fragment Shader.
//piece of fragment shader
struct MandelbrotBase
{
    int width, height;
    float zoom;
    int precsn;
    int depth;
    pt pos;
};

uniform MandelbrotBase mb = MandelbrotBase
    (
        1280, 720, //width, height
        300., //zoom
        100, 100, //precision, depth
        pt
        (
            1280 / 2,
            720  / 2
        )
    );

The problem is that I want to pass MandelbrotBase from the C++ program. I would be able to pass the uniform variables separately, but I want to pass entire structure:
const int width = 1280, height = 720;
struct MandelbrotBase
{
    int width = ::width, height = ::height;
    float zoom = 300.0f;
    const int precision = 100;
    int depth = precision;
    struct
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    } pos = { width / 2, height / 2 };
} mb;
.....
    //message handler
    LRESULT OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
        POINT c{ GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        mb.pos.x -= c.x - mb.pos.x;
        mb.pos.y -= c.y - mb.pos.y;
        mb.zoom *= 2;
        mb.depth += mb.precision * 2;
        //Here pass MandelbrotBase to shaders
        InvalidateRect(0, false);
        return 0;
    }

The program produces following geometry:

I have already seen similar questions, but yet have not a full understanding of how the structures are being passed. As I understand, the information can't be passed directly to Fragment Shaders, maybe I am wrong.
Just in case, here is the full source code

Vertex shader, mandelbrot.vs

#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec2 coord;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    coord = vec2(gl_Position.xy);
}


Fragment Shader, mandelbrot.fs

#version 330 core
in  vec2 coord;
out vec4 color;
                                                                                       
struct pt
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct complex
{
    float r;
    float i;
};

struct MandelbrotBase
{
    int width, height;
    float zoom;
    int precsn;
    int depth;
    pt pos;
};
//uniform int width = 1280, height = 720;
uniform MandelbrotBase mb = MandelbrotBase
    (
        1280, 720, //width, height
        300., //zoom
        100, 100, //precision, depth
        pt
        (
            1280 / 2,
            720  / 2
        )
    );

//complex less than module mod
bool    lessCom (complex c, float mod)
{
    return  c.r * c.r + c.i * c.i < mod * mod;
}
//square of complex number
complex sqCom   (complex c)
{
    return  complex (c.r * c.r - c.i * c.i, 2 * c.r * c.i);
}
//sum of complex numbers
complex addCom  (complex c1, complex c2) 
{
    return  complex (c1.r + c2.r,  c1.i + c2.i);
}

vec3 calculateMandelbrotColor (float px, float py)// MandelbrotBase mb)
{
    float x = (float(px) - mb.pos.x) / mb.zoom;
    float y = (float(py) - mb.pos.y) / mb.zoom;
    complex c = complex ( x, y );
    complex z = c;

    int iterations = 0;
    for (iterations = 0; iterations < mb.depth && lessCom(z, 4); iterations++)
        z = addCom (sqCom(z), c);

    float r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;

    if (iterations < mb.depth / 4.0)
        r = iterations * 255.0 / (mb.depth / 4.0);
    else if (iterations < mb.depth / 2.0)
        g = iterations * 255.0 / (mb.depth / 2.0);
    else if (iterations < mb.depth)
        b = iterations * 255.0 / mb.depth;
    return vec3(r, g, b) / 256;
}

float gl2Screen (float c, int screenSize)
{
   return (c + 1) / 2 * screenSize;
}

void main()
{
    color  = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    color  = vec4((coord.xy + 1 ) / 2, 0, 1);
    vec3 cl = calculateMandelbrotColor (gl2Screen(coord.x, mb.width), gl2Screen (coord.y, mb.height));
    color  = vec4(cl, 1);
}


C++ code, WinAPI/ATL

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlwin.h>

//const int width = 800, height = 600;
const int width = 1280, height = 720;
struct MandelbrotBase
{
    int width = ::width, height = ::height;
    float zoom = 300.0f;
    const int precision = 100;
    int depth = precision;
    struct
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    } pos = { width / 2, height / 2 };
} mb;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, MandelbrotBase mb)
{
    os << "mb: zoom=" << mb.zoom;
    os << " precision=" << mb.precision;
    os << " depth=" << mb.depth;
    os << " pos={x=" << mb.pos.x << " y=" << mb.pos.y << "}";
    return os;
}

// OpenGL
GLuint vao;
GLuint programId = -1;
GLuint vbo, ebo;

// QUAD GEOMETRY
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Positions
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f,    // Top Right
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f,    // Bottom Right
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f,    // Bottom Left
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f     // Top Left 
};

// you can also put positions, colors and coordinates in seperate VBO's
GLuint indices[] = {
    0, 3, 1, // First Triangle
    1, 3, 2  // Second Triangle
};

bool checkShaderFailure(GLuint shaderId, bool report = true)
{
    using std::cerr;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    int success;
    //check what error was for individual shaders being compiled
    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success)
    {
        if (report) cout << "shader ok" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    char infoLog[1024];
    ::glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 1024, 0, infoLog);
    if (report) cerr << infoLog << endl;
}
bool reportLinkErrors(GLuint programId, bool report = true)
{
    using std::cerr;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    int linkSucceeded = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSucceeded);
    if (linkSucceeded)
    {
        if (report) cout << "program ok" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    char infoLog[1024];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, 1024, 0, infoLog);
    cerr << "Program Linking Error: " << infoLog << endl;
    return true;
}


std::string loadFileString(const char* shaderPath)
{
    using std::cerr;
    using std::endl;
    using std::string;
    using std::ifstream;
    using std::stringstream;

    ifstream shaderFile;
    shaderFile.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);
    try
    {
        shaderFile.open(std::string(shaderPath));
        stringstream shaderStream;
        shaderStream << shaderFile.rdbuf();
        shaderFile.close();
        return shaderStream.str();
    }
    catch (ifstream::failure e)
    {
        cerr << "Shader file not successfully read: " << e.what() << endl << "path: " << shaderPath << endl;
        throw e;
    }
}
GLuint loadShader(const char* shaderPath, int shaderType, bool report = true)
{
    int shaderId = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    std::string shaderCode = loadFileString(shaderPath);
    const char* shader = shaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shaderId, 1, &shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderId);
    if (checkShaderFailure(shaderId, report)) return -1;
    return shaderId;
}

GLuint loadProgram(const char* vertexShaderPath, const char* fragmentShaderPath, bool report = true)
{
    GLuint vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId;
    vertexShaderId = loadShader(vertexShaderPath, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderId = loadShader(fragmentShaderPath, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLuint programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);

    glLinkProgram(programId);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderId);
    if (reportLinkErrors(programId, report)) return -1;
    return programId;
}
int glProgramInit()
{
    ::programId = loadProgram("mandelbrot.vs", "mandelbrot.fs");
    if (::programId == -1) return -1;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &::vao);
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    glBindVertexArray(::vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    return 0;
}


int glProgramDestroy()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteProgram(::programId);
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    using std::size;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(::programId);

    glBindVertexArray(::vao); // binding VAO automatically binds EBO
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0); // unbind VAO

    glFlush();  // Render now
}

unsigned long long temp()
{
    static unsigned long long t = GetTickCount64();
    unsigned long long ret = GetTickCount64() - t;
    t = GetTickCount64();
    return ret;
}

class COpenGLWindow
{
protected:
    HGLRC hglrc = 0;
    HGLRC initOpenGL(HDC hdc)
    {
        using std::cerr;
        using std::endl;
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), 1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
            PFD_TYPE_RGBA,        // The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
            32,                   // Colordepth of the framebuffer.
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            24,                   // Number of bits for the depthbuffer
            8,                    // Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
            0,                    // Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE, 0, 0, 0, 0
        };

        int  newPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
        SetPixelFormat(hdc, newPixelFormat, &pfd);

        hglrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);

        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != err)
        {
            cerr << "GLEW Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        return hglrc;
    }

    LRESULT OnDestroy(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

        if (hglrc)
        {
            wglDeleteContext(hglrc);
            hglrc = 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }
};

class CMyWindow : COpenGLWindow, public CWindowImpl<CMyWindow>
{

public:

    CMyWindow() {}
    virtual ~CMyWindow() {}

    /////////////////////////// Message Handlers /////////////////////////////////
    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {

        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
        RECT rc = CWindow::rcDefault;
        this->GetWindowRect(&rc);
        rc.right = rc.left + width;
        rc.bottom = rc.top + height;
        this->SetWindowPos(HWND_TOP, &rc, SWP_NOZORDER);

        HDC hdc;
        COpenGLWindow::initOpenGL(hdc = this->GetWindowDC());
        ReleaseDC(hdc);

        temp();
        glProgramInit();
        cout << "oncreate " << temp() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnPaint(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
        HDC hdc;
        display();
        SwapBuffers(hdc = this->GetWindowDC());
        ReleaseDC(hdc);
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
        POINT c{ GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        mb.pos.x -= c.x - mb.pos.x;
        mb.pos.y -= c.y - mb.pos.y;
        mb.zoom *= 2;
        mb.depth += mb.precision * 2;
        //pass MandelbrotBase to shaders
        InvalidateRect(0, false);
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnDestroy(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        COpenGLWindow::OnDestroy(uMsg, wParam, lParam, bHandled);
        glProgramDestroy();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }


    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY,   OnDestroy)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE,    OnCreate)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT,     OnPaint)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_LBUTTONUP, OnLButtonUp)
    END_MSG_MAP()
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CMyWindow cwnd;

    HWND hWnd = cwnd.Create(NULL, CWindow::rcDefault, L"Hello", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
    cwnd.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}



Have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270846/when-should-i-use-std140-in-opengl

I don't see any glUniformNT or glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM... calls in your C++ code that would actually copy your Mandelbrot struct to the GPU and shaders.
If it's one time, should be in glProgramInit. If per frame, display.

@HughFisher Yeah, that's obvious, these are really missing. Because the question was, how to do it. I know how to pass uniforms, but I didn't know how to pass complex structures. Since your first reply I was able to solve the problem, thanks to your hint. So I can add an answer with solution if anyone is still interested.
